# Set delegate of viewcontrollers in UITabbarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, uitabbarcontroller

I have the following setup in my app:

A UITabbarController with 3 viewcontrollers, with embeded UINavigationControllers.
The 3 viewcontrollers inheret/superclass from a UIViewController subclass called "SVC", in order to implement elements which is used in all of the 3. viewcontrollers and prevent duplicated code. In this "SVC" class I have setup a delegate called "dismissDelegate" (which is used to tell when the tabbarcontroller is dimissed).

```
@protocol ModalViewDelegate <NSObject>

    - (void)didDismissModalViewFrom:(UIViewController *)viewController;

@end
   @property (weak, nonatomic) id <ModalViewDelegate> dismissDelegate;
```

My other viewcontroller which segues to the UITabbarController, implements this delegate in order to get information about, when the tabbarcontroller is dismissed.

the SVC class notifies the delegate of dismissal of the tabbar like so:

```
 [self.dismissDelegate didDismissModalViewFrom:self];
```

I now want to set the delegate of all the viewcontrollers which inherts from the SVC class (all the tabbar viewcontrollers) to this viewcontroller and I try to do this via the prepareToSegue method like so:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

   if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ToTab"]) {


        UITabBarController *tabBarController = segue.destinationViewController;

        for (UINavigationController *navController in  tabBarController.viewControllers) {


            for (UIViewController *vc in navController.viewControllers) {
                _SubclassVC = (SVC *) vc.superclass;
                _SubclassVC.dismissDelegate = self; 

            }

        }


    }

}
```

But I get the following error:

```
+[SVC setDismissDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xbca68
```

My questions:

1. Is this the right way to tackle this senario (get information about dismissal of a viewcontroller and setup this delegate in a subclass which is inhereted by multiple viewcontrollers)?
2. How do I manage to set my first viewcontroller as the delegate of all the viewcontrollers in the tabbar - the SVC class, so I can get notified when the tabbarcontroller is dimissed and solve the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
+[SVC setDismissDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xbca68
```

See the **+**

The plus sign idicates that you are calling a class method. You must have tried setting a class variable by a setter. But a property represents instance variables only. Therefore the setters and getters that are automatically generated are intance methods only. (starting with a minus **-** in error messages like this).

And that is what you do:

```
        _SubclassVC = (SVC *) vc.superclass;
        _SubclassVC.dismissDelegate = self;
```

For whatever reason (probably by mistake or misunderstanding) you take the vc instance and get its `superclass`. `vc.superclass` returns a class object, not an object (meaning not an instance, in Obj-C class objects are objects too). 
Then you typecast it to `(SVC *)` just to stop the compiler from throwing errors (or warnings - not sure).

Well, I guess that you wondered yourself why you have to typecast it at all. That's the reason :)

Next, you assign `self` to a property `dismissDelegate`. The compiler does that because you typecasted it to SVC* which does have a property `dismissDelegate`. The compiler will actually call the setter `setDismissDelegate` as usual in contructs like this.

BUT at runtime the message (or selector) setDismissDelegate: is not sent to an `SVC*` but to a `class` object. And the class `SVC` does not have a method (or selector) `+setDismissDelegate:` and therefore cannot resolve the message. And that is exactly what the error message is telling you.

All right, now we get to your questions. 
1. Well, it is not the way I would do it, but that is certainly one way of achiving it. 
2. If you want to stick with that unusual approach then do this minor change and you will get rid of the error:

```
for (SVC *vc in navController.viewControllers) {
    vc.dismissDelegate = self; 
}
```

There is no point in fetching the superclass object. If you cannot access the property of a superclass then you did something wrong with the inheritance chain. 
If you want to be on the save side:

```
for (UIViewController *vc in navController.viewControllers) {
  if (vc isKindOfClass:[SVC class]){  //BTW, this is good usage of the class object
    SVC *svc = (SVC*) vc;
    svc.dismissDelegate = self; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for your quick answer and help :). Since I am fairly new in programming in Obj-c and want to learn I would be very interessted in hearing the way you would do it? Thank you very much :).

Comment: That depends on the purpose. Most similar tasks can be acomplished by overwriting viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear. But I don't know WHY you are doing this. Using the delegate pattern, as you do, is not the worst idea. If you want to do that properly then declare its methods in a protocoll and check whether the protocol is conformed to before calling them. (The same thing basically but more elegant.) Though this may be a good use for the NSNotificationCenter and NSNotification objects. Again, without knowing the purpose it is hard to say.

Comment: Thank you for your comment :). The reason I have a UIViewController subclass called "SVC", is to implement elements which is used in all of the 3. viewcontrollers and prevent duplicated code, but I will try use viewWillAppear, viewWillDisappear instead :). So when I have declared a protocol (class) I would do something like   if ([_svc respondsToSelector:@selector(setDismissDelegate:)]) {, before setting the delegate, is that what you mean? The only thing this is used for, is to determine when the (modal) viewcontroller is dismissed :). Thank you for your help and kindness.

Comment: Well, when we asked for the WHY then we did not meant the fact that you are subclassing. There are neraly always good reasons for subclassing. The question is rather why do you need to be notified when some view controller underneath is being dismissed. This rather sounds like an archtiecture issue rather than a programming glitch.

Comment: Yes. You can always use `respondsToSelector` befor invoking a method. That is fine. And there is nothing wrong with that. On the contrary. But when you use a protocol, then you could use `conformsToProtocol:@protocol(name)` in a similar manner. That is more like a proper use of a delegation pattern.

Comment: Ahh, okay. The reason I need to get notified is that I need to fire a download action on my main "screen/viewcontroller", when a button is pushed in my modal presented viewcontroller. In order not to present mutiple modal viewcontrollers on top of each other, I dismiss the modal viewcontroller via the delegate message, which calls the download action, which then present a new modal viewcontroller on top of the main viewcontroller. Is this a bad way to do it ? :). Thank you.

Comment: No, that is fine. I must have misunderstood something. As you describe it, it is a perfect example for implementing a delegation.